# testing REST API . session issue

Tags: ruby, rest, testing, automation

I am facing problem in testing REST API. I tried to authenticate like following.

```
 response = RestClient::Request.new(
    :method => :get,
    :url => @my_url,
    :user => @my_user,
    :password => @my_pass,
    :headers => { :accept => :json,
    :content_type => :json
    }
  ).execute
```

Also I tried https://username:password@www.xyz.com/api/1/contacts/list

Server side code :

```
def self.list(usr, id = false)
        data = { list: [], breadcrums: [] }
        current = usr.documents.find(id) if id
        query = if !id;
            usr.documents.where(node_tree: []).only(:file_name, :mime_type, :updated_at, :id, :oauth_provider_id, :tags)
        else
            folder_id = Document.get_oauth_id(folder)
            usr.documents.where(parent_id: folder_id).only(:file_name, :mime_type, :updated_at, :id, :oauth_provider_id, :tags)
        end
        result = query.sort_by{|doc| doc.file_name.downcase}.to_a
        result.each { |v| data[:list] << v.attributes.merge({ provider: v.oauth_provider.oauth_key, id: v.id.to_s}) }
        data[:breadcrumbs] = Document.breadcrumbs(current, usr) if id
        data
    end
```

But Problem is, When I try to authenticate from code. Internal server error thrown (500)
Problem might be with, they taking information to process from session. How Can I do ? If you didn't understand please let me know. I will try to elaborate. How to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Use a mocking library such as [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock), to abstract away external services when testing:

```
stub_request(:get, "user:pass@www.example.com")

Net::HTTP.start('www.example.com') {|http|
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new('/')
  req.basic_auth 'user', 'pass'
  http.request(req)
}    # ===> Success
```

Comment: I did the same. how to get the content from the request? for example : when I hit www.example.com/getdocuments/  It will return response in json format. How Can get that from above code.?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough, when you wrote testing I assumed you meant actual unit tests. There you would abstract out calling the actual api and just make sure you send the correct messages out.
If you are getting a 500 response from an external service then it most likely is broken and you should contact the provider or use another service.